# What is the diff between AVAudioPlayer vs MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

which one is better and what is the difference between them, AVAudioPlayer or MPMusicPlayerController.

Please share your ideas.
Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 1):

**AVAudioPlayer** is able to play one song at a time. It cannot access iPod Library means you cannot play songs which are present in user's iPod's Library. But biggest advantage I see is AVAudioPlayer can play songs when your app is in background.

**MPMusicPlayerController** is used to play songs from a playlist you pick using MPMediaPickerController from iPod Library which is a plus point. It accesses many properties of song which AVAudioPlayer cannot. It cannot play music in background.

Comment: MPMusicPlayerController can also play songs when your app is in background

Comment: AVAuioPlayer can play songs from the media library, but only if they are on the device: it cannot play users items that are in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer is more lightweight and suited for playing single songs at a time

MPMusicPlayerController requires more resources because it has more features and is designed to play playlists containing several songs